# Excel VBA-For Each to loop through OLEObjects in named range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write the most perfomant for each loop I can to loop through applicable checkboxes and change their status.

1. The first line of the below code (commented out) works but loops through all OLEObjects on the active sheet (about 200 on the sheet) and the "If" statement inside of the for each loop limits the action to only the check boxes that have the group name property of strRangName that I pass to the sub.
2. The second line does not work and would be the preferred method, which is to loop through only the OLEObjects in defined named range.  This would eliminate the need for the "if" statement in the for each block.
3. The third line does work if I pre-define the custom collection but the process of pre-defining it also looping through all OLEObjects on the sheet.  So it is no faster.

Any ideas on implementing the 2nd option would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

```
            'For Each obj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
            For Each obj In Names(strRangeName).RefersToRange '.Range(strRangeName)
            'For Each obj In subSystemCollection
                If Not obj.Object.GroupName = strRangeName Then
                Else
                    With obj
                        .Enabled = False
                        .Object.Value = False
                    End With
                End If
            Next obj
```

Comment: you may want to try posting your question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ also since you already have a working solution and are looking for better performance.